# is it possible to add more than one website under the same root on sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I wonder if i can make/add a website with totally different content under my sitecore root that already existed and named the website url differently with existed one?

for example
my sitecore root url-> http://himonolive.com/
but i want to make another under that root named with -> http://hollamonolive.com/

is it possible? 
also let me know is there any references article about this.

thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Add details in your question about the tree structure you are trying to achieve in the Content Tree and which site URL should point to which node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be doable by setting the correct Root item and Start item in the site definition.
Regards
S Baskar